# MathJax contradiction symbol? (\lightning)

Tags: support, mathjax

I like to use the `stmaryrd` symbol $\lightning$ for contradictions, but `\require` doesn't support `stmaryrd` nor `wasysym` (both packages have the lightning). Are there any *MathJax* alternatives?

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing a lightning-bolt symbol used for a contradiction, so I suspect it will confuse a number of readers. Most common in my experience is $\, \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow\ \ $

Comment: It is common in our university, and it looks cool :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MathJax [has a `\unicode` extension](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3717/83702), so you can specify the codepoint of a desired symbol per `\unicode{x21af}` (for the contradiction lightning) as in

$$\dotsc\implies 3 = 4\quad\unicode{x21af}.$$

Comment: Thanks, that's what I hoped for. Playing around with its size now.

Comment: I found $\unicode{x26A1}$ and $\unicode{x2607}$ also.

Comment: Testing `huge`: $\huge\unicode{x21af}$ `Large` $\Large\unicode{x21af}$

Comment: You can even simply put the character verbatim in the code: $1+1 = 2 ↯.$ It also works for the size: $\Huge ↯$.

Answer (score 9):

Honestly, I generally think that words are better than symbols here, especially when there is no universal "contradiction" symbol. So I'd suggest to go with something to the effect of

> ..., this is a contradiction.

Comment: Sometimes I find this too clunky. Especially when giving a one-line proof for a small remark via contradiction. (If $X$ were $Y$, then $1=0$ _\lightning_) reads more compact and can be ignored more easily by the eye if the reader isn't interested.

Comment: I get what you're saying. If it's a contradiction to a basic mathematical fact, I'd probably leave out any further indication and rely on the reader being able to discern that a contradiction has been found. (_I.e._, if I'm quickly trying to convince someone that every `foo` is `bar`, I might just leave a parenthetical remark to the effect of "otherwise $4$ is prime".) In other cases I generally prefer to point out _what_ is being contradicted (some assumption, some more advanced fact, etc.).

Comment: I rarely see the lightning symbol. I have usually seen "$\rightarrow\leftarrow$" or "$\perp$" as a contradiction symbol.

Comment: @robjohn: You should watch The Flash. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: when I do, I see a [blue spot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_blindness) for several minutes :-)

Comment: I'm a first year maths student and have already seen the lightning symbol and another symbol, ※ used by teaching staff.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.